# Include JSP with java dependecy in Google APP Engine

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine

I have a JSP file what is included each time I need it. This JSP file uses a Java variable to fill up my header. Something like this:

```
<h1><span class="header-title"><span><%=title%></span></span></h1>
```

Where title is defined in the another JSP file where I have including this line.

The way I include my JSP file is:

```
<%@ include file="myLittleJSP.jsp" %>
```

However, I have tried this one but I don't get my goal:

```
<jsp:include page="../myLittleJSP.jsp" />
```

My goal is to deploy succesfully... but when I am doing the deploy, Eclipse shows an error: JSP's can't be compiled.

What is wrong?
Diego.

Comment: Can you post the error please.

Comment: I've fixed it. Now I can deploy my project. No my fault, it was with google compiler.